# HP ENVY 14 bootup errors

Tags: boot

I have HP ENVY 14  laptop. I install the ubuntu 22.04 desktop version and am up to date. But I face this error at power on boot time.
How to fix it?

```
[    2.507445] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    2.530277] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    2.845113] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
[    2.845352] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    2.845512] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    3.094920] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
[    3.095136] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    3.095293] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 in HP ENVY 14 Laptop

Comment: Sounds like a kennel bug. [Please report it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). More importantly does Ubuntu boot and work correctly after showing this error?

Comment: Those errors are basically not for you. These notifications are about a mismatch between BIOS and kernel. A possibble fix would be to upgrade your BIOS.Dangerous AND there is no way yet to know if a new one fixes it so please ignore these messages.  The alternative is to wait for a new kernel where they can address these.